# Query LinqToXML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

My app needs to share and to recover data from a .xml file.
My .xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Postes>
  <Ligne ID ="1" Nom="SAVD">
    <Poste ID ="1">
      <Nom>CFL_D 1</Nom>
    </Poste>
    <Poste ID ="2">
      <Nom>CFL_D 2</Nom>
    </Poste>
    <Poste ID ="3">
      <Nom>CFL_D 3</Nom>
    </Poste>
    <Poste ID ="4">
      <Nom>CFL_D 4</Nom>
    </Poste>
    <Poste ID ="5">
      <Nom>CFL_D 5</Nom>
    </Poste>
    <Poste ID ="6">
      <Nom>S&amp;G_D 1</Nom>
    </Poste>
    <Poste ID ="7">
      <Nom>S&amp;G_D 2</Nom>
    </Poste>
  </Ligne>
  <Ligne ID ="2" Nom="SAVG">
    <Poste ID ="1">
      <Nom>CFL_G 1</Nom>
    </Poste>
    <Poste ID ="2">
      <Nom>CFL_G 2</Nom>
    </Poste>
    <Poste ID ="3">
      <Nom>CFL_G 3</Nom>
    </Poste>
    <Poste ID ="4">
      <Nom>CFL_G 4</Nom>
    </Poste>
    <Poste ID ="5">
      <Nom>CFL_G 5</Nom>
    </Poste>
    <Poste ID ="6">
      <Nom>S&amp;G_G 1</Nom>
    </Poste>
    <Poste ID ="7">
      <Nom>S&amp;G_G 2</Nom>
    </Poste>
  </Ligne>
  <Ligne ID ="2" Nom="SAR">
    <Poste ID ="1">
      <Nom>PT 1</Nom>
    </Poste>
    <Poste ID ="2">
      <Nom>PT 2</Nom>
    </Poste>
    <Poste ID ="3">
      <Nom>PT 3</Nom>
    </Poste>
    <Poste ID ="4">
      <Nom>PT 4</Nom>
    </Poste>
    <Poste ID ="5">
      <Nom>Finition 1</Nom>
    </Poste>
    <Poste ID ="6">
      <Nom>Finition 2</Nom>
    </Poste>
    <Poste ID ="7">
      <Nom>Finition 3</Nom>
    </Poste>
  </Ligne>
</Postes>
```

I would like to list the workstation (Poste) according to the attribute "Nom" of the element "Ligne".

When I do :

```
var query = from data in xelement.Descendants("Poste")
                    select data.Element("Nom").Value;
```

I recover all the workstation's names.

```
CFL_D 1
CFL_D 2
CFL_D 3
CFL_D 4
CFL_D 5
S&G_D 1
S&G_D 2
CFL_G 1
CFL_G 2
CFL_G 3
CFL_G 4
CFL_G 5
S&G_G 1
S&G_G 2
PT 1
PT 2
PT 3
PT 4
Finition 1
Finition 2
Finition 3
```

When I do :

```
var query = from data in xelement.Descendants("Ligne")
                    where (string)data.Attribute("Nom").Value == "SAVD"
                    select data;
```

I recover the following element :

```
<Ligne ID ="1" Nom="SAVD">
<Poste ID ="1">
  <Nom>CFL_D 1</Nom>
</Poste>
<Poste ID ="2">
  <Nom>CFL_D 2</Nom>
</Poste>
<Poste ID ="3">
  <Nom>CFL_D 3</Nom>
</Poste>
<Poste ID ="4">
  <Nom>CFL_D 4</Nom>
</Poste>
<Poste ID ="5">
  <Nom>CFL_D 5</Nom>
</Poste>
<Poste ID ="6">
  <Nom>S&amp;G_D 1</Nom>
</Poste>
<Poste ID ="7">
  <Nom>S&amp;G_D 2</Nom>
</Poste>
```

But I don't find how to merge the two queries to recover the names of the "poste" element only when the line's attribut is filtered.

Could you explain my error ?

Comment: In order to solve the problem, we need to write a second "from" inside the query like this.

`var query = from data in xelement.Descendants("Ligne")
                        where (string)data.Attribute("Nom").Value == "SAVD"
                        from data_2 in data.Descendants("Poste")
                        select data_2.Element("Nom").Value;`

Comment: have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Yes. The query in my last comment is the answer.

Comment: you can do it by one query like ``var postes = xElement.Descendants("Ligne")
                .Where(x => x.Attribute("Nom").Value == "SAVD")
                .Descendants("Poste")
                .Select(x => x.Element("Nom").Value);``